# Div items out of div

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new html developer, i am using bunch of divs in my page.

Issue is some of div items are not within div although they are defined within div tag.

**What am i missing here to understand? How to make sure that all items within div will get rendered within div?**

Comment: CSS/HTML layout questions would be better asked on http://doctype.com instead of on SO.

Answer (score 5):

No code? Time to get the crystal ball out then…

You are either absolutely positioning them (which takes them out of normal flow) or floating them, which [stops them from influencing the height of the container.](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) There are a number of ways to [force containers to wrap floating content](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a container that has a child that floats, that is why the parent div collapses.

```
<div id="parent" title="this collapses">
  <div style="float:left" title="child div"></div>
</div>
```

I think your problem is that the parent collapses.

The solution would be one of the following

1. float that parent div (where possible).
2. add a style overflow:hidden or auto to the parent div.
3. add a class of clearFix*  to the parent div(see below).
4. set a height (where possible).

*clearfix:

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
height: 1%;
}
```